# YouTrack instance totally private

Tags: youtrack

does someone know how to configure YouTrack so it's totally private (only invited users and no visibility to guests except the login-form)?

Thanks

Comment: This is a question for JetBrains' support, not SO.

Answer (score 1):

If you get a commercial plan, all the projects will be private. You can learn about the pricing here: https://www.jetbrains.com/youtrack/buy

Answer (score 1):

That's what I got from Jetbrains team:

- Buy Standalone version
- Host it on own servers
- Ban Guest user
- Disable sign up

This helped me.